# Adsense Site navigation rejection

Tags: google-adsense, google-adsense-policies, navigation

I have a website that I would like to monetize with Adsense. I keep receiving the same feedback from Adsense when submitting :

> Site Behavior: Navigation
>
> As stated in our Program policies, sites or
> apps displaying Google ads should provide substantial and useful
> information to the user. Users should be able to easily navigate
> through the site or app to find what products, goods, or services are
> promised.
>
> Examples of misguided navigation include, but are not limited to:
>
> - False claims of downloadable or streaming content
> - Linking to content that does not exist
> - Redirecting users to irrelevant and/or misleading webpages
> - Text on a page unrelated to the topic and/or business model of the website.

I submitted the web site multiple times, trying to solve potentially problematic issues but I keep receiving the same feedback.

Do anyone have experience in solving similar issues or have an idea what I should do ?

The url of the site is : sun dash direction dot com

Comment: What is the topic of the website and which of those examples might apply?

Comment: I have posted the link to the website, but I noticed that my question was edited. Here is the link : sun-direction.com

The website draws the direction of sun on google maps and gives additional information such as sunset time, dawn time ...